# Fazer upload de ficheiros em Asp.NET MVC 4 - Web API - Método Http Put

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, multiple-file-upload

Então, eu tenho que fazer um método no meu controlador para uma API que aceite 2 ficheiros via PUT (1 json e1 xml para processamento de dados, não para guardar os ficheiros), e tenho que enviar o request pelo fiddler.. 
O meu pedido no fiddler é o seguinte (método PUT):

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data
Authorization: XXXXX 
Host: XXXX
```

Request Body:

```
<@INCLUDE *C:\Users\ZZZZ.json*@>
<@INCLUDE *C:\Users\XXXX.xml*@>
```

Aqui está o código do meu controlador até agora (não funciona)

```
[HttpPut, Route("api/Student/{studentId}/Classes/{classId}")]
        public async Task<string> Put(int studentId, int classId)
        {
                var file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Count > 0 ?
            HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0] : null;
            Stream fileContent = await this.Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            MediaTypeHeaderValue contentTypeHeader = this.Request.Content.Headers.ContentType;

            if (fileContent != null)
                return "ok";
            return "not ok";
        }
```

Até agora o ficheiro não está a fazer o upload ne, aparece na variável "Request". Também não tenho a propriedade Request.File. Tentei também o HttpContext e também não tinha nada.

Tentei exatamente a mesma coisa mas com o método POST (acrescenta boundaries automaticamente no pedido do fiddler, e aí consigo ver os nomes dos ficheiros no meu controlador, mas não consigo ler nenhum deles...

O que fariam para por isto a funcionar? Tenho mesmo que ter um objeto em json e outro diferente em xml... Os ficheiros têm uma estrutura dinamica, ou seja não vale a pena criar um objeto específico para os mesmos.

PS : Como iriam depois ler os mesmos ficheiros sem os guardar em disco primeiro?

Answer (score 0):

Se eu entendi bem, você quer receber no controller os arquivos sem que precise de uma model para cada tipo (xml, json) ?

Já tentou usar o tipo dynamic nos parâmetros do controller ?

```
public async Task<string> Put(dynamic student, dynamic class)
{
   //Logica...
}
```

> Ref.: Usando o tipo dynamic: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic